# Where is the best place to validate that a user is authenticated in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm working in a application where I need to verified that request comes from authenticated users. Because I made a lot of loads base on user Guid.

Example

```
public ActionResult ManageEmployee()
{
      var loadedEmp = GetLoadedEmp(GetLoggedUserGuid());
      return View("Employee/Manage", loadedEmp);
}
```

My question is, do I need to do this "verified that the user is authenticated"

```
public ActionResult ManageEmployee()
{
 if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
 {
        return View("Account/LogOn"); 
  }

  var loadedEmp = GetLoadedEmp(GetLoggedUserGuid());
  return View("Employee/Manage", loadedEmp);
}
```

on every ActionResult function or is there a beast approach or centralized solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the [`AuthorizeAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.aspx) on the Action in the controller to require users to be logged in to perform said Action:

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult ManageEmployee()
{
    // This code will only execute if the user is Authenticated
    var loadedEmp = GetLoadedEmp(GetLoggedUserGuid());
    return View("Employee/Manage", loadedEmp);
}
```

When using that attribute, the user will be automatically redirected to the login page if they are not logged in (as long as your app is configured properly).

Answer (score 6):

@Justin Niessner is right, but as a shortcut if you want an attribute to be applied to every action in your controller you can just put the AuthorizeAttribute on the class:

```
[Authorize]
public class HomeController : AreaController { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you also use this attribute to lock down on a specific roles and users - should you use the role provider functionality.